# Разница в размерах одинаковых структур

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Решил написать класс для манипуляции BMP изображениями. Поскольку мне не нравится стиль WinAPI кода решил переопределить структуры `BITMAPFILEHEADER` и `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, но столкнулся со странной проблемой: размер переопределённой структуры больше размера WinAPI-структуры.
Код:

**WinAPI:**

```
typedef unsigned short      WORD;
typedef unsigned long       DWORD;

// ...

typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    WORD    bfType;
    DWORD   bfSize;
    WORD    bfReserved1;
    WORD    bfReserved2;
    DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER, FAR *LPBITMAPFILEHEADER, *PBITMAPFILEHEADER;
```

**Мой код:**

```
using Byte = unsigned char;

using Word = unsigned short;

using Dword = unsigned long;

// ...

struct FileHeader {

    Word    type = 0x4D42;

    Dword   size;

    Word    reserved1 = 0;                  

    Word    reserved2 = 0;

    Dword   offsetBits;

};
```

Суть проблемы:

```
size_t winApi = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER); // = 14
size_t my     = sizeof(FileHeader);       // = 16
```

Не могу понять почему размеры различаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, используемое вашим компилятором выравнивание по умолчанию приводит к таким фокусам. Укажите явно выравнивание хотя бы на 2 байта, а не на 4.

В VC++ примерно так:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)

... СТРУКТУРА

#pragma pack(pop)
```